# How do I add the total value of a column that is formatted in different currencies rates in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, currency, quantmod

I have a column named "transfer_fee" that comes from a table I cleaned up named cleanedmg. In this column I have different amounts of currencies as fees. It is a big data set so I probably have around 40 or more different currencies. Ex: 1.99EUR, 20,00NOK, 1.700,00HUF. I was wondering how I can unify the data into one currency and add it, or add every different currency together individually. I was trying with the quantmod library, however I did not quite figure it out. The data is maybe around 3,000 columns and all formatted weirdly like the example. I am using tidyverse for data wrangling.

Here is the code I have tried thus far:

```r
cleaned_moneygram <- 
  moneygram_prices %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(transfer_fee = 9) %>%
  rename(destination_country = 2) %>%
  separate(time, into = c("year","time"),sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(year = substr(year,1,4)) %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>%
  mutate(firm = "MoneyGram") %>% 
  select(c("send_country","destination_country","payment_method","year","exchange_rate","transfer_fee","firm"))
```

Comment: Please could  you provide an example of code.

Comment: cleaned_moneygram <- moneygram_prices %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(transfer_fee = 9) %>%
  rename(destination_country = 2) %>%
  separate(time, into = c("year","time"),sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(year = substr(year,1,4)) %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>%
  mutate(firm = "MoneyGram") %>%
  select(c("send_country","destination_country","payment_method","year","exchange_rate","transfer_fee","firm"))

Comment: I would just need to format the "transfer_fee" column, as it contains fees in different currencies as chr. Ex: 75,00 CZK, 1,99 EUR, 20,00 NOK

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps separate the values and the currency into distinct columns, then use case_when based on currency to apply different conversion factors to get a single currency output that you can add up.

Something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)
cleaned_moneygram <- moneygram_prices %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename(transfer_fee = 9) %>% 
  rename(destination_country = 2) %>% 
  separate(time, into = c("year","time"),sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(year = substr(year,1,4)) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>% 
  mutate(firm = "MoneyGram") %>% 
  select(c("send_country","destination_country","payment_method","year","exchange_rate","transfer_fee","firm")) %>% 
  separate(transfer_fee, into = c("value","currency"),sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(tfer_fee_usd = case_when(
    currency == "USD" ~ value * 1.0,
    currency == "EUR" ~ value * 1.2,
    currency == "NOK" ~ value * 1170.5,
    currency == "UOF" ~ value * 123.2
  ))
#> Error in as_tibble(.): object 'moneygram_prices' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>